# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:"

Tags: java

I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: num1
> at calificacion.main(problema_3.java:17)

after type the first value on this simple terminal java program:

```
import java.io.*;

class num
{
int num1,num2,num3;
}

class calificacion
{
public static void main(String []Args)throws IOException
{
BufferedReader ob1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
num DQ = new num();

System.out.println ("Ingrese primera calificación:");
DQ.num1 = Integer.parseInt(ob1.readLine());
System.out.println ("Ingrese segunda calificación:");
DQ.num2 = Integer.parseInt(ob1.readLine());
System.out.println ("Ingrese tercera calificación:");
DQ.num3 = Integer.parseInt(ob1.readLine());

System.out.println("\n\n");
System.out.println("Calificación final: "+(DQ.num1+DQ.num2+DQ.num3)/3);

}
}
```

on the other hand this one runs just fine and I am using the same input method in both:

```
import java.io.*;

class num
{
int numero;
}

class paroimpar
{
public static void main(String []Args)throws IOException
{
BufferedReader ob1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
num DQ = new num();

System.out.println ("Ingrese un número entero para determinar si es par o impar:");
DQ.numero = Integer.parseInt(ob1.readLine());
System.out.println("\n\n");

if (DQ.numero%2==0){
System.out.println(DQ.numero+" es par.");
} else {
System.out.println(DQ.numero+" es impar.");
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this matter but please declare your main class `calificacion` to be `public`.  Also it would help if you indented the code you post here properly.  What you have now is just a mess.

Comment: This error means that you most likely made some changes to the code but you did not recompile all your source files, so that when you run it, the program is using an old compiled class. Solution: Make sure you recompile all your source files (and that there are no compilation errors) before you run your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question would be much more readable if you'd format your code and follow Java naming conventions. If you're using an IDE, you may well be able to ask it to format your code for you.

It would also help if you'd give details about how you're compiling and running the code - I have a sneaking suspicion this may be due to not recompiling everything.

Comment: Jesper probably has it right.  I'll add that you have two classes named `num` and in the same package.  They're from different projects, but they can leave artifacts on your hard drive and the compiler will get confused.  Better to put your assignments in a package and not reuse class names like that.

Comment: Hello and thanks your answers. I am just learning java on my programming subject at college, actually this is my first homework on this java subject and I tryed to copy the format my "Teacher" used on his example. These simple codes are not part of any project they are just random .java files I made. I really cant figure out why the second code runs and the first one does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As You can read here this error states that You're missing field `num1`.
There is short [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nosuchfielderror) regarding `NoSuchFieldException`.

About Your issue. It's not because of the code (I've successfully compiled and run that). I believe it's because of compilation. Do you have those classes in the same directory? During compilation `javac calification.java` there should be two files out `calification.class` and `num.class`.
When You compile the second one it may override `num.class`.

How to solve this issue?

- use different directories / packages
- change one of the `num` classes names so they don't interfere

BTW. In Java we tend to start classes names with capital letter and variables with camelCase, so it's easier to read :)

Hope it helps! Happy coding!

Comment: I see. That must be the problem. I made both files in the same folder so one of them is trying to use the class num file from the other one. Thanks!!